# Definition of conversation in botframework

Tags: botframework

I am a bit confused on the definition of a "conversationId". Can anyone explain what a conversation is exactly? My use case needs a state for a group conversation, as long as the bot is the group, I want to maintain that state.

I also want to know how differentiate group conversation vs conversation with one user.

Answer (score 0):

The [Message Types](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/message-types/#navtitle) documentation explains the messages for begin and end conversation for users and bots. This page also indicates that messages are channel specific, meaning that some channels will send a conversation message and others might not. So, once you choose your channels, you'll need to experiment or read the channel specific documentation to see if they send messages for start and end conversation. To prepare, the Bot Framework Emulator has a drop-down list with a Send button so you can test how your code handles these messages.